# How can I have a vector that's strict in its values, like a normal type with bangs (!)?

Tags: haskell

Some common [performance advice](http://johantibell.com/files/haskell-performance-patterns.html#%285%29) in Haskell is to make fast data structures "spine strict" so that the structure, but not necessarily its contents, is fully evaluated as it is created. This lets us do more work when we insert a value and the structure is in cache as opposed to putting it off until we look a value up.

With a normal data type, like the binary trie from [Data.IntMap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-IntMap.html), this can be accomplished by making the relevant fields in the data structure strict:

```
data IntMap a = Bin {- ... -} !(IntMap a) !(IntMap a)
              | {- ... -}
```

(Excerpt from the [Data.IntMap.Base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/src/Data-IntMap-Base.html#IntMap) source.)

How can I achieve the same behavior if I want to store the children in a vector rather than directly as fields of `Bin`?

```
data IntMap a = Bin {- ... -} (Vector (IntMap a))
              | {- ... -}
```

Comment: Could a `Data.Vector.Strict` module be built on top of the regular one? I couldn't find any prepackaged one in hackage.

Comment: Looking at the common API in [`Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html) I find one method `basicClear` that seems intuitively impossible to implement for strict vectors of arbitrary element type (there is no polymorphic strict value to reset to). I don't know how important it is...

Comment: Side note: inside data structures I would most likely use `Data.Primitive.Array` instead of `Vector`, because there's likely no need for slicing, and therefore no need for the extra two words per node.

Comment: @AndrasKovacs: oh, good advice, didn't know about that module.

Comment: Is this now answered? If so, could someone answer it and could it be accepted plz?

Comment: @JulianLeviston: I still don't know a good answer to this :/. I think you can come close by manually using `seq` or `deepseq` in your code and perhaps adding an `{-# UNPACK #-}` annotation to the vector or array (similar to how [`Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/src/Data.Vector.html#Vector) is defined), but I'm not sure this is *exactly* like what I was asking about.

Comment: Ah. Sorry for the noise. I've since realised stack overflow isn't really about the accepted answers (had a convo on meta about this)

Answer (score 5):

First, I'll answer a simple variant of the question: 
If your data type is unboxable, e.g. you want a strict vector of `Int`s,
use [`Data.Vector.Unboxed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html).
As a free bonus, the implementation allows you to have "structure of arrays", `(Vector a, Vector b)`, even the interface
is less error-prone "array of structures", `Vector (a, b)`.
See [Wikipedia on AOS and SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOS_and_SOA).

---

Yet, in the OPs question, we want to stick `IntMap a` into `Vector`, and
`IntMap` isn't unboxable (or storable or primitive).

The various options boil down to the same idea: you have to `seq` values yourself.
Whether you go for
[`Data.Primitive.Array`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.6/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html)
or implementing own `Data.Vector.Strict` on top of `Data.Vector` (note: `basicClear` can be no-op as
it is for unboxed vectors, or you can use `unsafeCoerce ()` as a dummy value),
you will `seq` values. This is how
[`Data.Map.Strict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) is implemented on top
of the same lazy structure as `Data.Map.Lazy`.

For example
[`map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/src/Data.Map.Strict.Internal.html#map)
`Data.Map.Strict` is implemented as:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
map f = go
  where
    go Tip = Tip
    go (Bin sx kx x l r) = let !x' = f x in Bin sx kx x' (go l) (go r)
```

Compare that to `Data.Map.Lazy.map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
map f = go where
  go Tip = Tip
  go (Bin sx kx x l r) = Bin sx kx (f x) (go l) (go r)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now a package for this: [strict-containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-containers) which provides strict vectors in the [Data.Strict.Vector](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-containers-0.2/docs/Data-Strict-Vector.html) module.